# Gulp not creating temp files

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

Apologies if this has been asked 1000 times before.. but i couldn't find an answer that worked for me! Unfortunately i'm following along with a course on Udemy but cannot get the answer there either..

IM currently trying to create another styles folder when editing my current CSS file. - I am using Atom as my IDE and running on a macbook pro.

Gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  console.log('Created a gulp task');
});

gulp.task('html' , function() {
  console.log('Something with HTML');
});

gulp.task('styles' , function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/assets/styles/styles.css')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/temp/styles/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {

  watch('./app/index.html', function() {
    gulp.start('html');
  });

  watch('./app/assets/styles/**/*.css', function() {
    gulp.start('styles');
});

});
```

Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "HIDDEN"
  },
  "keywords": [
    ""
  ],
  "author": "KeithyBoi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "HIDDEN"
  },
  "homepage": "HIDDEN",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-postcss": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you running that with "gulp watch"?  just running "gulp" will do nothing because your 'default' task doesn't trigger your 'watch' task.  If you are just running "gulp" change the default task to gulp.task('default', ['eatch'], function() {

Comment: Hi, yes that is running with Gulp watch, and the terminal does pick up the changes.. however the folder doesnt get created? which is confusing!

Comment: It is working fine on my system.  I copied your code.  Only difference is I have gulp installed globally as well as locally.

Comment: Thanks for trying mark. I really have no idea why its not working..

Comment: You might try "npm install --global gulp-cli" install those globally to see if it makes a difference.  I don't think it should but ...

Comment: Yeah still no joy.. im going to try it no my pc and if see if its my macbook thats the problem

Comment: So it turns out im an idiot.. and had my css file called style.css and not styles.css as instructed in my Gulp file. Problem solved! Thanks for your help though Mark.